# Работа с массивами PHP

Tags: php, php7, php7.4

Есть два массива:

1. ```
   Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [NAME] => aaa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [NAME] => bbb
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 7
            [NAME] => ccc
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5
            [NAME] => www
        )
     )
   ```
2. 

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 5
)
```

Как сделать результирующий массив, в котором, в случае совпадения ID из первого со значениями второго (7,3,1,5), будет хранится NAME?

Comment: Вы изучали циклы?  А условия `if`?

Comment: Не понимаю, какое условие if должно быть. Первый массив преобразовал в одномерный.

Comment: по первому надо (проще) пробегаться через foreach, по второму в принципе можно на выбор любой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создаём пустой массив
2. Запускаем цикл foreach по первому массиву
3. Внутри первого цикла запускаем второй цикл по второму массиву
4. Внутри второго цикла через `if` проверяем, если `ID` из первого цикла равно элементу второго - складируем `NAME` в подготовленный массив
5. Делаем `break`;
6. PROFIT

Answer (score 0):

возможно такая вариация нужна?

```
$arr1 = [['id' => 1, 'name' => "a"], 
         ['id' => 2, "name" => 'b'], 
         ['id' => 3, 'name' => "c"]
       ];
$arr2 = [1,3];

$tmp = array_column($arr1, 'name', 'id');
$result = array_intersect_key($tmp, array_flip($arr2));
```